# Should functions always called back-to-back be wrapped inside a new function?

Tags: design

If I have two functions that I repeatedly use back-to-back, should I wrap those functions inside a new one? For example, I have:

```
def prepare_data(data):
  # do a few lines of data prep
  return prepared_data

def process_data(prepared_data):
  # do a few lines of processing
  return result
```

These two functions always run one after the other. In fact, if I see `process_data` without `prepare_data` in front of it, it's a bug. I call these functions several times throughout my codebase. Given this, is it a good design to create a wrapper function that calls both of them? Like so:

```
def prepare_and_process_data(data):
  prepared_data = prepare_data(data)
  result = process_data(prepared_data)
  return result
```

This way I'm just calling one function throughout the codebase.

Comment: Is the downvote because it's so obviously I *should* or so obvious I *shouldn't*? Or so obvious that there is no general principle and it's subjective?

Comment: I might also have `prepare_data` set a field or flag in the data, and `process_data` raise an exception if that flag is not set.

Comment: I vote not to create the wrapper function until you think of a better name. The name should tell me less about how it works and more about what it’s for.

Comment: Related: [Sequential coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712131/sequential-coupling-in-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In fact, if I see process_data without prepare_data in front of it, it's a bug.

Then in this specific case, yes. Put them into a `prepare_and_process_data` function.

This might not apply for *all* function calls that are found together, but if you see the same groups of functionality being used in the same way, then it's probably time to *refactor* that pattern into its own function.